# Make Login Vulnerable to SQL Injection Login Bypass

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, sql-injection

I am working on a school project about SQL Injection.  I created my own Netbeans login form to show a login bypass with SQL Injection. I used this youtube video as reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vauM7axnRs since this is my first time working with Netbeans or any database building.  The form works and I made fake login credentials but I haven't been successful bypassing the form.  I believe it is because I am using prepareStatement which is preventing the attack.

```
import java.awt.Color;
*import java.sql.PreparedStatement;*
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

private void jButton_LoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    PreparedStatement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    //get username & password

    String username = jTextField1.getText();
    String password = String.valueOf(jPasswordField1.getPassword());

    //make sure username and passord are from query
    String query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?";

   // show a message if the username or the password fields are empty
    if(username.trim().equals("username"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Your Username", "Empty 
    Username", 2);
    }
    else if(password.trim().equals("password"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Your Password", "Empty 
    Password", 2);
    }
    else{
    try {
        st = My_CNX.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);

        st.setString(1, username);
        st.setString(2, password);
        rs = st.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next())
        {
            //show new form
            Main_Menu form  = new Main_Menu();
            form.setVisible(true);
            form.pack();
            form.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            //close the current form (login_form)

            this.dispose();

        }
        else{
            // error message
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username / 
    Password","Login Error",2);
        }

    }


     catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login_Form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
```

I looked at some examples online where they use regular Statement and createStatement which is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.  I changed the prepareStatement but I get an error with the SQL Syntax. The error I get is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND `password` = ?' at line 1

```
import java.awt.Color;
*import java.sql.Statement;*
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

private void jButton_LoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    //get username & password

    String username = jTextField1.getText();
    String password = String.valueOf(jPasswordField1.getPassword());

    //make sure username and passord are from query
    String query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?";

    // show a message if the username or the password fields are empty
    if(username.trim().equals("username"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Your Username", "Empty 
    Username", 2);
    }
    else if(password.trim().equals("password"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Your Password", "Empty 
    Password", 2);
    }
    else{
    try {
        st = My_CNX.getConnection().createStatement();


        rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        if(rs.next())
        {
            //show new form
            Main_Menu form  = new Main_Menu();
            form.setVisible(true);
            form.pack();
            form.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            //close the current form (login_form)

            this.dispose();

        }
        else{
            // error message
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username / 
    Password","Login Error",2);
        }

    }


     catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login_Form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
```

I am using MySQL. If there is a way to make the login form vulnerable or a query I can use even with the prepareStatement, or I just have something wrong, I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not terribly familiar with NetBeans or Java, but should be able to help you out.

When you're using `createStatement`, you aren't substituting the question marks.  You need to populate the query with the values from the form.  That's what the MySQL error is saying.  It's sending literal question marks.

I think you are right that `prepareStatement` is causing you problems.  [According to the documentation](https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface), the question marks are place-holders, where you use `setInt, setString, setFloat`, etc. to sanitize user input.

### SQL Injection Attack

The point of a SQL attack is to trick the application into doing something it wasn't supposed to.

So based on your code, since you aren't sanitizing user input, entering the following password should delete the table:

```
hunter2; DROP TABLE USERS;
```

Once you do the variable substitution, the query will look like this to MySQL (new lines added for clarity):

```
SELECT * FORM `users` WHERE `username` = q13 AND `password` = hunter2; 
DROP TABLE USERS;
```

Comment: With the first example I gave with the prepareStatement, I would get no errors with the question marks as place holders.  Can you clarify what I would need to replace to use the createStatement or what I would need to replace the question marks with?

Comment: You need to replace the question marks with the input provided by the user.

Comment: Ok. I appreciate your help.